# Sqlite Net PCL DateTime Precision

Tags: c#, sqlite, sqlite-net

I need to save a datetime value with miliseconds precision - e.g.: "11/28/2019 09:59:40.777" - in the table *"Journal"*, I am using a trigger for it.

This is my Model:

```
public class Journal
{
    public int IdAluno { get; set; }
    public int IdAulaProfessor { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(typeof(JournalOperacao))]
    public int IdOperacao { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataHorario { get; set; }
    [ManyToOne(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.CascadeRead)]
    public JournalOperacao JournalOperacao { get; set; }
}
```

The SQLiteConnection contructor:

```
SQLiteConnection = new SQLiteConnection(DbFilePath);
```

The trigger

```
DbConnection.Execute(@"CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS JournalInsertTrigger
                                       AFTER INSERT ON DiarioFalta
                                    BEGIN
                                       INSERT INTO Journal (IdAluno, IdAulaProfessor, IdOperacao, DataHorario) VALUES (new.IdAluno, new.IdAulaProfessor, 1, (strftime('%s', 'now', 'localtime') + 62135596800) * 10000000);
                                    END;");
```

When the trigger inserts a row, the column "DataHorario" only saves the date and time, but I need the miliseconds too.
I have already tried `(julianday('now') - 2440587.5)*86400.0`, but the value I get is *"1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM"*

```
var journal = JournalData.GetItems();
var row = journal.First();
```

The value of `row` is

```
value = { DataHorario = "1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM", IdAluno = 144600, IdAulaProfessor   = 1821540, IdOperacao = 1 }
```

Comment: You want it to insert current date you can then simple format it yourself no ? `var date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.fff");`

Comment: @Franck you mean put `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.fff")` inside Insert Statement ?
`var sql = "INSERT INTO Journal VALUES ("+DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.fff")+")";` ?

Comment: @AlanNunes  That will not help since the DateTime value is being inserted in the trigger.  It must be a function compatible with sqlite SQL.

Comment: @Franck  That will not help since the DateTime value is being inserted in the trigger. It must be a function compatible with sqlite SQL.

Comment: @AlanNunes SQLite doesn't have a datetime type. As the docs explain, you can save either a Unix timestamp with *seconds* precision, or a readable ISO8601 string. Use the string. The trigger is wrong to begin with and you can't really see what it produces. You already have problems with it. Imagine if you were in the UK, when 1-1-1970 was *summer time*.

Answer (score 1):

After writing the initial answer, it wasn't until the end that I perceived your question is lacking sufficient detail.  The very last line of the question says "the value I get is..." but you don't actually show how you are getting that value.  Also, you show the C# model, but not the SQLite table definition.  Ultimately to get a full solution that works correctly both within SQLite and between the C# model, you need to provide more details of how data is being read and converted between the model and the database.  I hope my answer helps anyway.

---

As a reference see the SQLite document page for [date and time functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

- Within SQL to get the full date-time string format with millisecond precision requires the complete format string using `%f` for fractional seconds like SS.SSS.  It produces a string like '2019-11-28 10:27:27.146.:

  `strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%f', 'now', 'localtime')`

  - Because `strftime()` primarily returns string values, it is *incorrect* to apply addition or multiplication.  Since SQLite has no native date-time data type, there is no automatic conversion for handling mathematics.  There is also *no need to manipulate the value* since it already has millisecond precision in the last digits like SS.SSS.
- The numeric date-time value returned by the function `julianday()` already contains millisecond precision.  For simply storing the date/time value, there is *no need to manipulate the value* with multiplication or subtraction.

  - To get the current local time:  `julianday('now', 'localtime')`
  - To get the corresponding string representation, pass the Julian numeric date/time value to the `strftime()` function like the following examples:

    `strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%f', julianday('now', 'localtime'))`

    `strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%f', julianDayColumn)`

    `strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%f', 2458815.93573086)`
- The Unix epoch format (seconds since 1970-01-01) like `strftime('%s', 'now', 'localtime')` does NOT keep millisecond precision, only seconds precision... it records only integer seconds without any fractional part.

If I recall correctly (sorry I can't test right now), the official .Net library `System.Data.Sqlite` will automatically convert between .Net `DateTime` values and the SQLite string values using standard interfaces, however I'm not sure if this is true for the millisecond precision.  Such automatic conversion might require that the table column be declared as `DATETIME` type.

Whatever the case, you will need to handle the dates within pure SQL differently than the conversion between SQL and .Net/C#.  Within SQL (e.g. inside triggers, SQL update and insert statements, etc.) you need to use the SQLite date and time functions.  Within C# and the .Net framework, you will want the value converted to the .Net `DateTime` type.  But that conversion likely does not require the forced multiplication and subtraction--those manipulations will usually ruin the date-time values unless you already know exactly what you are doing and for what reason... not just guessing at formats.

If you are trying to following recommendations from other sites, I see various attempts at storing and retrieving ticks and Unix Epoch values, etc.  Such attempts will likely ruin the ability to store and manipulate dates within SQL including triggers and will likewise prevent storing millisecond precision.

Answer (score 0):

My only intention was to save a date time with miliseconds precision, but I wasn't getting it because SQLite-Net-PCL creates the column data type table `DateTime`(C#) as `bigint`(SQLite) and I was using `strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%f','now', 'localtime')` which returns a string type.

Since I'm not interested in manipulating the column `DateTime DataHorario` I changed the model column `DateTime DataHorario` to `string DataHorario`, which fixed my case.